# Logging errors in google analytics

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Apart from general JavaScript knowledge, this snippets requires someone who knows how to properly use Google Analytics API.

To log errors on my site, I use this code:

```
try {
  window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    var file = e.filename.substr(e.filename.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    // for some reason, filename sometimes contained path, sometimes just name
    if(file.length==0)
      file = e.filename;
    var msg = file+":"+e.lineno+":"+e.colno+" \""+e.message+"\" Browser: "+navigator.userAgent;

    if(typeof ga=="function") {
      ga('send', 'event', 'jserror', 'click', msg, {'transport': 'beacon'});
    }
    else {
      // This is executed when google analytic is not loaded
      // which happens in debug mode
      console.error(msg);
    }
  });
}
catch(e) {
  console.warn("Failed to add error callback.");
}
```

I'm especially interested to know whether I'm using the google analytics API correctly. Maybe I could log the data about error in multiple columns?

I'm new to google analytics so feedback is very valuable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ga('send', 'event', 'jserror', 'click', msg, {'transport': 'beacon'});
```

Yup, that's how I would do events in Google Analytics. However, the API also provides a special call for errors. It's found under [Exception Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/exceptions).

```
ga('send', 'exception', {
  'exDescription': msg,
  'exFatal': false
});
```

Another is that you're wrapping an `addEventListener` call into a `try-catch`. Not sure why this is required. The callback is fired asynchronously, thus the `try-catch` will make no sense (unless somehow, `window` or `addEventListener` doesn't exist)

```
if(typeof ga=="function") {
```

The snippet (and not the script that it loads) creates the global `ga` function for you, which means the global `ga` should be present when the snippet is present. It's seen in the snippet as this portion:

```
i[r]=i[r]||function(){...}
```

But I see that it's possible that you're not loading it when debugging. So this can be ignored I suppose.

Lastly, rename `e` to `error`. This makes the variable tell what it is more.